# SQL - Using SELECT in the WHERE clause of another SELECT

Tags: sql, select

i have next query

```
select No, 
       Description, 
       Item,
       Date
from myTable1
```

and get

[image]

and just one select

```
select * from myTable2
```

and get

[image]

Now I need to select from MyTable1 all data and join with MyTable2

and get sum of *quantity*

group by *NO* and  *ITEM*

where MyTable2.Date <= MyTable1.Date

Any idea?

I want to get this table

[image]

Comment: What have you tried so far? And it's always better to provide expected result based on given example

Comment: Show us the expected result as well. (With that input data.)

Comment: I don't have idea

Comment: Share the query if you have tried anything so far.

Comment: question is not clear so far

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Also: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this to get you started, without more info it is difficult to produce an accurate answer:

```
SELECT T1.No
     , T1.Item
     , SUM(T2.Quantity)
     , MIN(T1.Date) as Date FROM mytable1 T1
  INNER JOIN mytable2 T2 
       ON T1.No = T2.No AND T1.Item = T2.Item AND T2.Date <= T1.Date
  GROUP BY T1.No, T1.Item
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
select t1.*,sum(t2.quantity)
from myTable1 t1
INNER JOIN mytable2 t2 on t2.no = t1.no and t2.item=t1.item
WHERE t2.date<=t1.date
GROUP BY t1.No,t1.item
```

Answer (score 1):

Try This.

```
            SELECT 
            T1.No,
            t1.Description , 
            T1.Item, 
            MIN(T1.Date) as Date ,
            SUM(T2.Quantity) as Quantity
            FROM Table1 T1 INNER JOIN Table2 T2 
            ON T1.No = T2.No AND T1.Item = T2.Item AND T2.Date <= T1.Date
            GROUP BY T1.No, T1.Item , T1.Description
```

let us know if you have any quetions.

Answer (score -1):

SELECT No,Description,Item,Date,sum(t2.quantity) 
FROM myTable1
JOIN myTable2 ON myTable1.No = myTable2.No and Description = item
WHERE MyTable2.Date <= MyTable1.Date
GROUP BY No,Description,Item,Date

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
SELECT T1.No, T1.Description, T1.Item, T1.Date, sum(T2.Quantity) 
FROM myTable1 T1 
LEFT JOIN myTable2 T2 
ON T1.No = T2.No AND T1.Item = T2.Item AND T1.Date >= T2.Date 
GROUP BY T1.No, T1.Item;
```